# Deploy sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have created simple application in windows sharepoint services. Now I want to deploy that solution. For that I have taken backup of my site and FTP that backup to remote server. I have create Blank Webapplication on my remote server. What I want to do is now simply restore this backup on blank webapplication on remote server. I have sharepoint designer installed on my remote server. When I try to open blank site in sharepoint designer on remote server It is asking me for authontication. I have Administrative credential and when I enter that to validate It was giving me error while opening site.

Can anybody tell me what is the cause of it. As I cant able to open site in designer I couldn't able to restore backup on it and my deployment get fails.

Or is there other way to deploy WSS site on remote server..?

Thanks in advance

Sachin

Comment: What is the error? Access denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could infer from your question that you have just created a new SharePoint Web Application &  and no Site COllection for you to open the Site in the SharePoint Designer you will need a Site Collection. To server you need best option I would suggest is to use backup & restore option of the STSADM command. here is how you need to do it.

In the your source server type the following command

```
STSADM -o backup -url [url of the application you want to backup] -filename [name & path for the file where you want to store the backup]
```

Now copy the backed up file to the remote server.In the remote server create a Blank application as you did earlier and run the below command

```
STSADM -o restore -url [url of the new application] -filename [name & path for the file where you have the backup]
```

Thats it. You are ready to go. Please note that if you have any WebPart,dll ,feature ect you need to deploy them seperatly to the remote server. Best way to do it is to us the SharePoint Solution Infrastructure.Search for SharePoint WSP Solution you will ample number of resource.